# Instagram Scraping with endpoints requires authentication for all requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, md5, instagram-api, hashlib

As you know, Instagram announced they has changed their endpoint apis this month.
Looks like in the wake of Cambridge Analytica instagram has changed up their endpoint formats and require a logged in user session for all requests.....

Not sure which endpoints need updating but I was specifically using the media/comments endpoints which are now as follows:

Media OLD:

https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&id={0}&first=100&after={1}

Media NEW:

https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%2221575514%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQAHXuz1DPmI3FFLOzy5iKEhHOLKw3lt_ozVR40TphSdns0Vp5j_ZEU6Qj0CW6IqNtVGO5pmLCQoX0Y8RVS9aRTT2lWPp6vf8vFqjo1QfxRYmA%22%7D

The script that I used for avoiding this problem is as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import json

#CHROME_UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
CHROME_UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'

def getSession_old(rhx_gis, csrf_token, variables):
    """ Get session preconfigured with required headers & cookies. """
    #"rhx_gis:csfr_token:user_agent:variables"
    print(variables)
    values = "%s:%s:%s:%s" % (
            rhx_gis,
            csrf_token,
            CHROME_UA,
            variables)
    x_instagram_gis = hashlib.md5(values.encode()).hexdigest()

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {
            'user-agent': CHROME_UA,
            'x-instagram-gis': x_instagram_gis
            }
    print(x_instagram_gis)
    session.cookies.set('ig_pr', '2')
    session.cookies.set('csrftoken', csrf_token)

    return session


def getSession(rhx_gis, variables):
    """ Get session preconfigured with required headers & cookies. """
    #"rhx_gis:csfr_token:user_agent:variables"
    values = "%s:%s" % (
            rhx_gis,
            variables)
    x_instagram_gis = hashlib.md5(values.encode()).hexdigest()

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {
            'x-instagram-gis': x_instagram_gis
            }

    return session


if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = { 'user-agent': CHROME_UA }
    response = session.get("https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez")
    data = json.loads(response.text.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
    csrf = data['config']['csrf_token']
    rhx_gis = data['rhx_gis']
    variables = '{"id":"460563723","first":10,"after":"AQBf8puhlt8nU2JzmYdMMTuH0FbMgUM1fnIOZIH7n94DM4VLWkVILUAKVB-5dqvxQEI-Wd0ttlEDzimaaqwC98jccQaDQT4tSF56c_NlWi_shg"}'
    session = getSession(rhx_gis, variables)

    query_hash = '42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44'
    encoded_vars = urllib.parse.quote(variables, safe='"')
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=%s&variables=%s' % (query_hash, encoded_vars)
    print(url)
    print(session.get(url).text)
```

I am sure this script was working well before 11 days ago, but not working now.
Does anyone know the solution how to get user posts without authenticating?

Comment: maybe, nobody can help me for this solution. :(